# Index was out of range error. But when i excecute item.count() returns 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm having issues with razor, I'm trying to access the first element of a list. But when I try to cast an element with `item2.hijos[0].ruta`, I get an error.

But when I use `item2.hijos.count()`, it returns 1. So there is an element but somehow razor doesn't want me to access it.

Here is my code. `items2.hijos.first()` doesn't work either.

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li id="@(item.CNombreManual)" onclick="mostrarEsconderHijos(this.id)" class="list-group-item-heading">@(item.CNombreManual)</li>

    foreach (var item2 in item.hijos)
    {
        <li id="_@(item.cNombreManual)" class="list-group-item" style="tex-align:left; display:none">
        @(item2.CNombreManual)
        @Html.ImageActionLink("Ver PDF", "Descargar", "Manual", new { NombreArchivo = item2.hijos[0].Ruta }, null, "~/imgs/LecturaPdf.png")
        </li>
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the debugger and examine `item2.hijos` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether you have the items in the array item2.hijos[] before using the array. It could be printing the values for the first few records and then throwing an error where there is no element. So it can be happening for any hijos array of item2 of item. Just ensure you check for the array size before using it.

```
item2.hijos[0].Ruta // replace this with the following

item2.hijos.Length > 0? item2.hijos[0].Ruta : 0
```

I think you can even do shorter. `item2.hijos[0]?.Ruta ?? 0`

Comment: thanks! this did solve the problem! i had to adjust it a bit cus ruta is string. i put it here so anyone with the same issue can check my edit as well ####- 
item2.hijos.Count() > 0? item2.hijos[0].Ruta:"0"  -####

Comment: @SergioHenrySilvaNavarro, great to hear it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your model, but the problem is that you're iterating (foreach) of item's hijos, but then accessing of item**2**'s hojos.

I think you want to access `item2.Ruta`:

```
 foreach (var item2 in item.hijos)
 {
   (...) item2.Ruta // not item2.hijos[0].Ruta
```

If you actually need to access item2.hijos[0].Ruta then you need check if it exists first.

You can do that using:

- item2.hijos.[Count()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0)
- item2.hijos.[Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0)

You could also use `item2.hijos.FirstOrDefault()?.Ruta` (see [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0)).

Btw. the whole hijos could also be null, so it may be necessary to check if the whole collection (item2.hijos).

Finally, you may want to add another `foreach` for `item2.hijas` rather than access element 0.